# Session Management in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

I have to implement session management in a Struts 2 application.

My Current Implementation: When the user logs in I put the userid in a session variable.

I have a custom interceptor which is called for each action that user performs. In the interceptor I check whether that session variable has a userid or not. If userid is null in the session variable I redirect to the login page. Upon logout the session object is invalidated.

Question: User logs in to the application. If I open one more tab and enter the url context path, it is again going to the login page which is wrong. How do I deal with this? If the user is already logged in, the next tab should take him to the home page, not login.

Comment: Post the code relevant to your question.

Comment: very strange because normally differents tabs share the same session... Have you debug your interceptor to see what is in the session at different times ?